# Magento : sort by category problems?

Tags: magento, product, catalog

When I have products in categories ( I have sub-categories in this category) I don't have sort by category just sort by price. I want to add sort by category with sort by price.

For example :

if i have computer category and i have laptop and Desktop sub-categories. I have many products also in computer category. When i am in computer catalog i wish to show also in navigation layer :

```
Sort by
 Category :
   Laptop(1)
   Desktop(2)
```

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento base theme provides this feature by default
using these 2 files
base/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<catalog_category_default translate="label">
      <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
....
</catalog_category_default>
```

And base/default/template/catalog/navigation/let.phtml and of course there is Block class to provide data.

To use this feature your product should belong to child as well parent category or your parent category's display setting Is Anchor should be set "Yes", then it will display all products including products in children categories as well with category filter.

Comment: you dont have to add anything. this is provided by default so just check that your product categories allocation are meeting required condition to display Sort By Category. If not then then your catalog.xml or catalog/navigation/let.phtm file is wrongly modified

Comment: but i don't modified any think and i don't display this sort by category

Comment: May be these file are overridden in youar theme from base theme.Experiment in a fresh installation of magento, I'm sure you will see proper category filter then just comapare whats wrng with your theme